# Excel VBA Macro: Attempting to write something to pull data from various spreadsheets into one (harder circumstances inside)

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

So I am trying to pull information from one column in every sheet I have in my workbook.  There are currently 506 sheets.  Each one has a different number of rows and each sheet has its own unique name.  Each sheet's data that I want starts at row 8, and it is in column J.  I am trying to print all of these to the C column in a page I have called test which is in the same workbook but is not counted in the 506 sheets that I mentioned earlier.  This is what I've written so far:

```
Sub Test()
Columns(3).Insert
For i = 1 To i = 506
    Do While Worksheets(i).Cells(i + 7, 10) <> Null
        Worksheets("test").Cells(i, 3) = Worksheets(i).Cells(i + 7, 10)
    Loop
Next i

End Sub
```

I just started with this today but I have experience with a lot of other languages so my syntax may be somewhat off too.

Thanks in advance for any advice/hints that any of you genius people can offer

Comment: You're trying to use `i` for two different things - the worksheet index and the row index. Try declaring and using `j` for the row index and have an inner `For` loop. Also an empty cell won't be `Null` either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description was diferent from your code so I guessed...  I  think this is close to what you want...

```
Sub Test()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


     For I = 1 To WS_Count

        ' ONLY IF it is not TEST
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name <> "TEST" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEST").Cells(1, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Cells(7, 10)

        End If

     Next I

  End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked great for getting one row. The thing is I want to get many rows from the J column in each sheet. I tried doing    R_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Rows.Count  where R_Count is a long and then there is a nested for loop (J) from 8 to R_Count where J is a long.  When I changed Cells(7, 10) to Cells(R_Count, 10) it came out as an infinite loop and the application stops responding.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I figured it out.  Thanks again for the big help.

Comment: @DavidHarmon,  That is great!  Could you please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the green down arrow on the left of the answer and then the up arrow if you found it "useful"?